# Including .php files with Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-4

I have to use [jcart](http://conceptlogic.com/jcart/) Carting with a project that I just started building on with Laravel.

With usual php projects, the steps involved is just dumping the 'jcart' folder in the root, and referring the paths to the jcart.php, and jcart.js files.

I just started with laravel, and it's getting really confusing for me figure out how to work with this.

In the front end file (using blade I understand), I need to include

```
/jcart/jcart.php
```

And in jcart.js file, I need to refer again to /jcart/jcart.php (and other files).

How ever, across the site, it keeps throwing not found errors in the javascript file.

I have dumped the jcart folder in /public/. Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: From what i see on the document, this is not compatible for "plug & play" with laravel. Try searching similar package for laravel, in packalyst.

Comment: @Nucleo1985 Which document are you referring to? Also, how can I get the correct paths every time I call the php file in javascript?

Comment: This one, http://conceptlogic.com/jcart/install.php from your link above. Check in your app.php for manual referring we can call it "plugin" on laravel.

Comment: Do you mean autoload.php in laravel?

Comment: No, i mean app.php. I edited my comment above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I do includes is as follows. Here is the folder structure of your Laravel project.

```
app
-> commands
-> config
...
-> includes
  -> jcart
    -> jcart.php
    -> config.php
    -> config-loader.php
    -> relay.php
```

By default, there is no `includes` folder, but it is perfectly fine to modify the `app` folder to suit your needs. If you follow this structure, you can then include a file using the following:

```
require app_path()."/includes/jcart/jcart.php";
require app_path()."/includes/jcart/config.php";
require app_path()."/includes/jcart/config-loader.php";
require app_path()."/includes/jcart/relay.php";
```

Hope that gives some insight!

**Edit**

Change the folder structure to:

```
public
-> assets
  -> js
    -> jcart
      -> php
        -> jcart.php
        -> config.php
        -> config-loader.php
        -> relay.php
      -> js
        -> jcart.js
        ...
```

Than you would change the `path` variable in jcart.js to:

```
var path = 'php',
// OR
var path = '../php',
```

And hopefully one of those should work.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I need to call this jcart.php from (/public/js/)jcart.js. How to do this?

Comment: I figured out how to include the .js files. I mean inside the .js file - I need to give the correct path to jcart.php?

Comment: Do you need the contents of the .php file or the data that jcart.php returns? Because one is using a filereader to get the plaintext content, while the other is using ajax to get the json returned data.

Comment: The js file contains ajax calls to .php files. So I need to just give the correct path to .php. 

If it's in app/includes, I am not sure how to call it via browser:

Comment: Thanks. I think that will work. Just trying that now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly how jCart integrates, but as far as the JavaScript only the files in /public/ are exposed to the web. If you had a file like /public/foo/bar.js you would refer to it using http://example.com/foo/bar.js.

Laravel has some [helpers](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers#urls) to automatically generate the correct URL. e.g.

```
$url = asset('img/photo.jpg');
```

At times Laravel can appear complex, but it really has some fantastic features.

Comment: Hey Tom. Thanks for the comment. Jcart is rather simple, if you can have a look. 

I need to call jcart.php (which includes config.php, config-loader.php, and relay.php) How ever, whenever I call /public/jcart 
it goes to not found.